# Where is my SQLite database created?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

I am following the tutorial presented here: [EF7 tutorial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html)

It seems to be a well-known tutorial about SQLite, UWP and EF7 all goes as expected when following it, but I was not able to find the physical path to the database created by the code-first approach.

This thing is quite strange I wanted to open the sqlite database using "DB Browser for SQL Lite" but I could not find it anywhere...

Did some of you follow this common tutorial and find the database or do you know where EF7 code first creates the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create an SQLite database without a specific path, it will be placed in the folder that your code can locate as `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`

For your DB Browser, it is in

```
c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<package-name>\LocalState\
```

`<username>` is obvious, `<pacakage-name>` can be found in your Package.appxmanifest, packaging tab. It looks like a Guid.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever the executable is run. If you check the code linked, you find a relative path and a database name 'Blogging.db'. I would look in bin\Debug or bin\Release folders. You could search for the 'Blogging.db' file

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=Blogging.db");
}
```

Comment: I was seeking also this file, but i did not found it, true that i never seek it at run time... Are you saying that this database file is generated only at runtime ? Is so... how the data from database is persistent between different sessions ?